# Error passing vertices to shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I'm beginning simple 2d gles 2.0 android application.
For some strange reason I always get one point in the center of the screen instead of vertex coordinates passed to the shader.
I'm clearly doing something wrong. Can't figure what.
[image: Lonely point]
P.S. I'm not using any projection matrices, because i need standard quad for drawing. tried projection - did not help.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GLSurfaceView glv = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glv.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer(this);
        glv.setRenderer(renderer);
        glv.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
        setContentView(glv);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SimpleRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private final float[] squareVertices = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,
    };
    private FloatBuffer squareBuffer;

    private final Context context;

    private int text_program;
    private int aPositionLocation2;


    public SimpleRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        squareBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareVertices.length * 4).asFloatBuffer();
        squareBuffer.put(squareVertices).position(0);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(text_program);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation2, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, squareBuffer);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 4);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation2);

    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        text_program = ShaderHelper.buildProgram(TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(context, R.raw.texture_vertex_shader),
                TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(context, R.raw.texture_fragment_shader));

        aPositionLocation2 = glGetAttribLocation(text_program, "a_Position");
        glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ShaderHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "ShaderHelper";

    public static int compileVertexShader(String shaderCode) {
        return compileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, shaderCode);
    }

    public static int compileFragmentShader(String shaderCode) {
        return compileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, shaderCode);
    }

    private static int compileShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
        final int shaderObjectId = glCreateShader(type);
        if (shaderObjectId == 0) Log.w(TAG, "Shader not created!");
        glShaderSource(shaderObjectId, shaderCode);
        glCompileShader(shaderObjectId);
        final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
        glGetShaderiv(shaderObjectId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
        Log.v(TAG, "Results of compiling source:" + "\n" + shaderCode + "\n:"
                + glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderObjectId));
        if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
            // If it failed, delete the shader object.
            glDeleteShader(shaderObjectId);
            Log.w(TAG, "Compilation of shader failed.");
            return 0;
        }
        return shaderObjectId;
    }

    public static int linkProgram(int vertexShaderId, int fragmentShaderId) {
        final int programObjectId = glCreateProgram();
        if (programObjectId == 0) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Could not create new program");
            return 0;
        }
        glAttachShader(programObjectId, vertexShaderId);
        glAttachShader(programObjectId, fragmentShaderId);
        glLinkProgram(programObjectId);
        final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        glGetProgramiv(programObjectId, GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        Log.v(TAG, "Results of linking program:\n"
                + glGetProgramInfoLog(programObjectId));
        if (linkStatus[0] == 0) {
            // If it failed, delete the program object.
            glDeleteProgram(programObjectId);
            Log.w(TAG, "Linking of program failed.");
            return 0;
        }
        return programObjectId;
    }

    public static boolean validateProgram(int programObjectId) {
        glValidateProgram(programObjectId);
        final int[] validateStatus = new int[1];
        glGetProgramiv(programObjectId, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, validateStatus, 0);
        Log.v(TAG, "Results of validating program: " + validateStatus[0]
                + "\nLog:" + glGetProgramInfoLog(programObjectId));
        return validateStatus[0] != 0;
    }

    public static int buildProgram(String vertexShaderSource,
                                   String fragmentShaderSource) {
        int program;
        // Compile the shaders.
        int vertexShader = compileVertexShader(vertexShaderSource);
        int fragmentShader = compileFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSource);
        // Link them into a shader program.
        program = linkProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

        validateProgram(program);

        return program;
    }

}
```

---

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = a_Position;
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
```

---

fragment shader:

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe someone knows reliable debugging tool to view vertex data inside shaders. Any help would be great. Spent already 2 days on this stupid issue!

Comment: Is onSurfaceChanged() called at least once? What are the values of width and height?

Comment: Yes, it's called right after onSurfaceCreated(), width=720 height=1022.

Comment: Did you try other vertex positions ? -1.0 and 1.0 would be on the edge of the screen and may be clipped (although that doesn't explain the point in the center). What about -0.5 and 0.5 instead?

Comment: Yes, I tried. The points are always displayed at (0,0), although I didn't specified this point. It looks like that zeroes array is passed to shader instead of squareVertices. Moreover, when I changed vertex shader to gl_Position = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1.0); point is placed in expected position (it is fat enough to be visible on screen edge).

Comment: Maybe try to add a call to glGetError after each other gl call, to see if something is not working. Either glVertexAttribPointer is not sending the values at the right place or squareBuffer contains zeroes somehow.

Comment: glGetError returns 0 in DrawFrame() and OnSurfaceCreated(). 
Now enough pain debugging pure OpenGL and shaders. Switching to LibGDX as a high-level graphic engine. Anyway, thanx for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed in passing vertex data: OpenGL uses native byte order (little-endian for x86 emu), but I have allocated buffer in java (big-endian I suppose) so corrupted float values were passed to vertex shader. After specifying byte order in byte buffer everything works fine.

```
squareBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareVertices.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
```